# updateOnDuplicate in sequelize bulkCreate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I call my service to create or update a person I got this error because of using updateOnDuplicate

```
await User.bulkCreate(
  [
    { id: 2, firstName: "Daniel", status: "disabled" },
    { id: 3, firstName: "Jackson", status: "pending" },
  ],
  {
    updateOnDuplicate: ["firstName", "status"],
  }
);
```

I found on StackOverflow that it doesn't work with PostgreSQL but this solution is mentioned on Sequelize website
https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/_sequelize_core.bulkcreateoptions#updateOnDuplicate

TypeError: s.replace is not a function
at Object.removeTicks

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: TypeError: s.replace is not a function
    at Object.removeTicks  I have this error

Comment: Do you use Sequelize v7?

Comment: I am using Sequelize 6.28.2

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, I traced the code into Sequelize and found the following:

If you have composite primary keys:

1. Things like this in the model are a strict no-no

```
indexes: [
                {
                    name: "test_pk",
                    unique: true,
                    fields: [
                        { name: "id_role" },
                        { name: "id_permission" },
                    ]
                },
            ]
```

This was especially due to using the `sequelize-auto` library, it generated fields as

```
[
    { name: "id_role" },
    { name: "id_permission" },
]
```

instead of `fields: ["id_role", "id_permission"]`

I am not sure if this is an expected behavior or not. but after changing it to `fields: ["id_role", "id_permission"]` the issue was solved.

The library was essentialy trying to remove `"` from an object `{ name: "id_role"}` which threw the error `s.replace is not a function`